# Find host package for cross-compiling with CMake

Tags: cmake, cross-compiling, host

I'm involved in some project, developing a library in C language.

Unit-tests in our project run python scripts to generate data for testing.

When the project is compiled for Linux or Windows, call to `find_package(Python3 COMPONENTS Interpreter Development NumPy)` in `CMakeLists.txt` works pretty well: Python is successfully found, data are generated.

However, when the project is cross-compiled on Windows for some embedded platform, that call to `find_package(Python3...)` always fails.

Recently I've learned that it can be debugged using internal CMake variable [`CMAKE_FIND_DEBUG_MODE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/variable/CMAKE_FIND_DEBUG_MODE.html)

So, I've wrapped the call to find_package in commands setting this variable to ON, then OFF.

Here is the relevant part of debug log:

```
CMake Debug Log at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/FindPython/Support.cmake:2681 (find_library):
  find_library called with the following settings:

    VAR: _Python3_LIBRARY_RELEASE
    NAMES: "python37"
           "python3.7"
    Documentation: Path to a library.
    Framework
      Only Search Frameworks: 0
      Search Frameworks Last: 0
      Search Frameworks First: 0
    AppBundle
      Only Search AppBundle: 0
      Search AppBundle Last: 0
      Search AppBundle First: 0
    CMAKE_FIND_USE_CMAKE_PATH: 1
    CMAKE_FIND_USE_CMAKE_ENVIRONMENT_PATH: 1
    CMAKE_FIND_USE_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH: 0
    CMAKE_FIND_USE_CMAKE_SYSTEM_PATH: 0
   
  find_library considered the following locations:

    C:/Anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/(lib)python37(\.so|\.a)
    C:/Anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/(lib)python3.7(\.so|\.a)
    C:/Anaconda3/envs/py37/libs/(lib)python37(\.so|\.a)
    C:/Anaconda3/envs/py37/libs/(lib)python3.7(\.so|\.a)
    C:/Anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/config-3.7/(lib)python37(\.so|\.a)
    C:/Anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/config-3.7/(lib)python3.7(\.so|\.a)
    C:/Anaconda3/envs/py37/(lib)python37(\.so|\.a)
    C:/Anaconda3/envs/py37/(lib)python3.7(\.so|\.a)
    ... other paths

  The item was not found.
```

Correct path to the python library is `C:\Anaconda3\envs\py37\libs\python37.lib`. Directory, containing this file, appears on the third place on the directory list above. So, if CMake would search for a file with `.lib` extension, it would find it.

However, extensions `.lib` or `.dll` never appear in the log.

At the same time, executable file of the python interpreter is found.

I think, it is because CMake tries to find python for the target platform. However, I need to run python on the host.

Is it possible to switch this behavior?

Search for "cmake find_host_package" brings only [this macro wrapping original `find_package`](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/SPIRV-Tools/blob/7403dfafd8a4b7216343dd9be891e540a5f30240/CMakeLists.txt#L221), that is incorrect

Comment: "I need to run python on the host." - So you only need to run Python, not to link with its libraries. Why do you use `COMPONENTS Development`? That way you explicitly ask for libraries which you don't need... See also documentation for [FindPython3](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPython3.html).

Comment: Yes, that's right. Removing `Development` has resolved the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with removing "Development" from requested components:

```
if(CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING)
    find_package(Python3 COMPONENTS Interpreter NumPy)
else()
    find_package(Python3 COMPONENTS Interpreter Development NumPy)
endif()
```